# How to change the content (value) of file "capacity-scheduler.xml" dynamically using REST APIs?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I  am trying to change the value of property "`yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent`" at the time when job is running in order to provide more resource unit to AM container. My basic logic is, more resource unit to AM, can run more `YarnChild`, results good throughput.

Comment: You can't change app master container at runtime. And it doesn't increase throughput. Adding more node managers does

Comment: API is here, if you tried to search for it https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Scheduler_Configuration_Mutation_API

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, Thankyou !!!  Can you please explain little more about application master and the resources consumed by its container ? what does this property really 
 mean "yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent" ? I read some paper saying when the value for this property is added (increase) then pending applications get chance to execute. what does it means ? Thankyou very much in Advanced !!!!

Comment: Application master is responsible for starting, waiting,  and watching the main application process. It's resources are typically less because there's no data processing happening there. I'm not really sure what information determines how large a YARN container gets based on the data it's processing

Comment: @cricket_007 Thankyou very much !!! Using "yarn rmadmin -refreshQueues" command i can implement the changed configuration to the resource manager. That works me. Actually i am doing my masters project and want to increase job number of job parallelism and its corresponding throughput. To achieve this, resources should be almost fully utilized during job execution time. Anyway it works, but for testing purpose i should use SWIM ahead. I am really blank with SWIM. If you have time, can you please suggest me something about SWIM benchmarks. Thankyou in advanced .

Comment: I have no idea what SWIM is, so best of luck to you. Also, I feel like most MapReduce projects should be using Spark anyway